# Arranging <td> in HTML email

Tags: html, responsive-design, html-email

I'm making a responsive email template. The problem I'm encountering is that I want the icon to be align left of the text. How can I accomplish this? I've been stuck for while on this.

Edit: This is an updatey update with text words because I can't save my changes unless I have more wordy words and less codey code.

```
<body yahoo="yahoo" bgcolor="#f6f8f1">
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <![endif]-->
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#f6f8f1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td class="header" bgcolor="c7d8a7">
          <table class="content" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="70" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td height="70" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
                      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/38a0Gpi.png" width="70" height="70" border="0" alt="" />
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                <table width="425" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <![endif]-->
                      <table class="col425" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 425px;">
                        <tr>
                          <td height="70">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td class="subhead" style="padding: 0 0 0 3px;">
                                  COFFEE SHOP
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="h1" style="padding: 5px 0 0 0;">
                                  Responsive Email Mockup
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                           </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

I wrapped the image in a `td` of its own by adding `</td><td>` after the `img`

```
<td height="70" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/38a0Gpi.png" width="70" height="70" border="0" alt="" />
</td>
<td>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
```

Comment: Yes, except this will be for an HTML email so there is no stylesheet. So, either inline styling or the CSS up top in the <style> tag.

And thank you! That makes sense :D